# Pyrocms Contact form in facebook tabs - displaying errors on page load

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, pyrocms

I'm trying to use the PyroCMS Contact form in a facebook tab.

When displaying the page directly, everything is OK, the form page is displayed as wished without error message.
https://facebook.noviris.com/tests/contact

When I integrate this page via a facebook page tab, it displays the form post errors on page load, not after using the submit button.
https://www.facebook.com/gwadaweb?sk=app_197712883656289

Comment: did you saw my answer? Please feedback... THX.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook send [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter to your page tab every time you arrives to your FB page. Firebug shows this clearly.

[image]

So a good solution is stop processing your form when this parameter is present.

```
if ($_POST['signed_request'])
{
    // do not process form
}
```

Firebug also show the referrer: https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy.php?v=4. Maybe you could use this too but do not seems very trusty that this location do not change.

Comment: have tried your solution this morning everything is working now ... great ... thanks for your help ...